# Swift UI why do I have 2 back buttons?

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I am trying to resolve an issue where I have 2 "back buttons" on my app view. This seems to be happening after I navigate twice. Once from the home screen to create account page, then again from the create account page to another page. Using the NavigationView [image: Two back buttons]

I am using this format to a different page.

```
struct CreateAccountViewGeo: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{

        GeometryReader { (deviceSize: GeometryProxy) in
            ZStack{
 NavigationLink(destination: SportPreference(), tag: 1, selection: self.$current) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    VStack (spacing: deviceSize.size.height * (20/812)){
                        Button(action: {
                            self.current = 1
                            print("Create tapped!")

                        }) {
                            Text("Create")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                .frame(width: deviceSize.size.width*(185/375), height: deviceSize.size.height*(50/812))
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .overlay(
                                    Capsule(style: .continuous)
                                        .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2)))
                                .frame(width: deviceSize.size.width, alignment: .center)

                        }//Close button for create
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have more than one `NavigationView{...}` some where

Comment: I only have one navigation view on the top of each of the 3 pages, so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: You only need one navigation view which is at home screen. You can’t add other navigationview in any subview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to E.Coms. Here's a clear example:

SwiftUI View1:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(YOUR_ITEMS) { ITEM in
                NavigationLink (destination: View2()) {
                    Text("GO TO VIEW 2")
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

SwiftUI View2:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(YOUR_ITEMS) { ITEM in
                NavigationLink {
                    View3()
                } label: {
                    Text("GO TO VIEW 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

So NavigationView {...} should be only declared in your first View, then just use NavigationLink.